# can't get some xml elements in <xsl:otherwise> block using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I get my required xml elements in  block.But at the same, i also put  block for catching other xml elements.But it is not worked for me...

**This is XML Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text1-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text2-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text3-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text4-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text5-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>

</w:body>
</w:document>
```

**This is XSLT File**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
 exclude-result-prefixes="w">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Document>

      <xsl:variable name="headingName" select="(//w:body/w:p/w:pPr/w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')])[1]/@w:val"/>
      <xsl:variable name="topLevelHeadings" select = "//w:body/w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val = $headingName]"/>

      <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="$topLevelHeadings">
          <Heading>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$topLevelHeadings">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
          </Heading>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="w:p">
             </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>

      </xsl:choose>   

    </Document>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="w:p">
    <Paragraph>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Paragraph>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:r/w:t">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My Generated Output is:**

```
<Document>
  <Heading>
  <Paragraph>Text2-</Paragraph> 
  <Paragraph>Text5-</Paragraph> 
  </Heading>
</Document>
```

**But My Required output is:**

```
<Document>
      <Paragraph>Text1-</Paragraph> 
      <Heading>
           <Paragraph>Text2-</Paragraph> 
      </Heading>
      <Paragraph>Text3-</Paragraph> 
      <Paragraph>Text4-</Paragraph> 
      <Heading>
           <Paragraph>Text5-</Paragraph> 
      </Heading>
</Document>
```

I think, **I have some problem with  Block**. So, Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your **xsl:choose** here is that it is only being used once, and it is checking only if there is at least one **w:p** element with a heading. So, you will only get one **Heading** element output. For you **xsl:choose** to work, you really need to use it within the **w:p** template

```
<xsl:template match="w:p">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')]">
         <Heading>
            <Paragraph>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </Paragraph>
         </Heading>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <Paragraph>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </Paragraph>
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

However, you don't really need the **xsl:choose** here. You can probably get away with just have a specific template to match **w:p** elements which have a matching **w:pPr** element

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')]]">
```

In this template you can then output the **Heading** element. You would then have a separate template to match all other **w:p** elements to output the paragraph, and if you give it a name, you could call it from the previous template too to share code

```
<xsl:template match="w:p" name="para">
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" exclude-result-prefixes="w">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <Document>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Document>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')]]">
      <Heading>
         <xsl:call-template name="para"/>
      </Heading>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:p" name="para">
      <Paragraph>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Paragraph>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:r/w:t">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following is output

```
<Document>
   <Paragraph>Text1-</Paragraph>
   <Heading>
      <Paragraph>Text2-</Paragraph>
   </Heading>
   <Paragraph>Text3-</Paragraph>
   <Paragraph>Text4-</Paragraph>
   <Heading>
      <Paragraph>Text5-</Paragraph>
   </Heading>
</Document>
```

Actually, the final template for `<xsl:template match="w:r/w:t">` isn't strictly needed, because the default behaviour for XSLT when it matches an element for which there is not a specific template is to output the text anyway.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will check it.In the mean time, Could you please tell me what is the problem with <xsl:choose> that i used here?.I have written lot of code based on that <xsl:choose> block.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to explain why the **xsl:choose** is not working in your case. Usually it is better to use template matching as it is more within the spirit of XSLT as a functionality language. It also helps with code re-use, and can make things more readable (by cutting down on indentation and nested code, for example).

Comment: Can i use not statement like this <xsl:template match="not(w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')]])">

Comment: If you mean to match **w:p** elements without a **w:pStyle**, then it would be written like this: `<xsl:template match="w:p[not(w:pPr/w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')])]">`

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple illustration of what is wrong, your xsl:otherwise block does `<xsl:apply-templates select="w:p">`. The context node at the time is the root node (/), so this is processing the w:p elements that are children of the root node, and there are no such elements, so it does nothing.

You're tackling some very complex XML here with very little experience in XSLT. It might be better to tackle some easier problems first - spend some time with an XSLT textbook or tutorial and work through the examples.